# Update Multiple Nested, User Input Array Values in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, database, mongodb, backend

In short, I'm trying to get user input and make changes accordingly from database. User inputs the cafe number, the image number they want to change text of and the 2 different language translations which will appear on frontend depending on browser language. I handled the change language part but I can't seem to change the nested JSON array variables with user input.

The JSON in question goes like this, explanation of variables below it

```
var items = {
    'lg' : cafeNumber,
    'img': {
             imgNumber: {
                            'english': enText,
                            'german': deText
                        }
            }
     }
```

What I'm doing here is this: Get user input for cafe number which is `cafeNumber`. Next, I get user input for the image number which they want to change with `imgNumber`.

This is the part where it gets tricky. We have multiple images in the system, and each of those images have 2 translations which need to be input. So the `img` string must be input with `imgNumber` and every `imgNumber` must have 2 different translations.

So I ask translations next with `enText` and `deText`. Then have them submit the form. These actions are all done by a single submit/post action. So they fill out the form, press submit and post action begins.

Problem comes where I can't seem to match `img` with `imgNumber`. `imgNumber` just returns as a string.

If I use the `insert` method with `items` variable, it works just fine. But if I try the `update` method -which is actually what I need-, manually using `find` or `findOneAndUpdate` methods, I can't seem to get it working.

I searched around and it seems `$` operator cannot update multiple variables. Any suggestions as to how I should solve this?

Some snippets of things I tried

```
db.collection('cafe').update({
    "lg": cafeNumber
  }, {
    "img": {
      imgNumber: [{

          "de": deText,
          "en": enText
        }]
      }
    }
  })
```

Not neat but I was trying every option (Although I logged this step by step and it seemed to return the same doc with all variables at every step so this is probably useless)

```
  db.collection('cafe').findOne({
    'lg': cafeNumber
  }, function (err, doc) {

    if (err) throw err;

    if (doc) {
     db.collection('cafe').findOne({
      'img': imgNumber
  }, function (err, doc) {

    if (err) throw err;

    if (doc) { 
    db.collection('cafe').update({
    'english': enText... etc.etc.
```

**Edit per request, also a TL;DR:**

The structure goes like this :

Every cafe has a unique `cafeNumber`. This determines which cafe is which.
`'lg'` is the string name in database, `cafeNumber` is the variable which the user inputs.

Inside these cafe entries, there are multiple images. `'img'`is the string name in the database, `imgNumber` is the variable which the user inputs.

Now, inside each of these `'img'` there are 2 variables: `'english'` and `'german'` which are the string names, and `enText`, `deText` which the user inputs themselves.

**This is the main thing, the whole process is so that the user can change the english and german texts on any image they want, the images themselves will already be on the server. So the code should find the user input matching `cafeNumber`, then find the user input matching image, and then update the `'english'` and `'german'` texts with whatever input the user has entered.**

The `'img'` tag is not required, now that I think about it.

An example structure that I would like to create would be :

```
'_id': 'blabla',
'lg': '1', //1 is input by user
'img': '2' //2 is also input by user
         { 
        'english': 'myWord' //myWord is input by user
        'german': 'dontknowgerman' //dontknowgerman is input by user  
         },
'img': '3' //3 is input by user
          {
         'english': 'lorem' //lorem is input by user
         'german': 'ipsum' //ipsum is input by user
         }
```

There can be any number of images, so the user has to input themselves which image is going to have their texts changed.

Comment: May I suggest you enhance your question a little by giving a concrete example of what data you have in your database, what input you get from the client and what you would expect as the result?!

Comment: @dnickless Thanks, updated my question for better clarification

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Can you provide some sample record, please and then the expected result of the modification operation?